# noexcept not removed by decay

Tags: c++, c++17

why doesn't `std::decay` remove the noexcept specifier from function pointers ?

for example this complies in c++17

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename>
struct is_noexcept {};

template<typename R, typename ... Arg>
struct is_noexcept<R(*)(Arg...)> : public std::false_type {};

template<typename R, typename ... Arg>
struct is_noexcept<R(*)(Arg...) noexcept> : public std::true_type {};

void test() noexcept {}

int main(){
    void (*b)() noexcept = test;
    static_assert(is_noexcept<decltype(b)>::value);
    static_assert(is_noexcept<std::decay<decltype(b)>::type>::value);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: @rubenvb because decay is often used to remove specifier from a type.

Comment: `std::decay` is meant to emulate what happens when passing something as a function argument; array becomes pointer, cv-qualification is stripped, reference is stripped. That's about it.

Comment: @Tyker [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) is defined to do exactly three things: decay an array to a pointer to its first element, make a function pointer out of a function (reference), or as you say remove const/volatile and any reference qualifiers the object's type may have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::decay` type transformation trait performs the conversions that occur when an expression is passed by value to a function template:

```
template <class T>
void f(T);

int main() {
    f(expr); // T is deduced to std::decay_t<decltype(expr)>
}
```

One such conversion is the function-to-pointer conversion, since functions cannot be passed by value. The function-to-pointer conversion preserves the `noexcept` specification of the function for type safety reasons, so `std::decay` does as well.

Comment: thanks, i miss understood the purpose of `std::decay`